# explain the main reason to use getColor() method from ContextCompat class?

Tags: android, converters, getcolor

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

i have these line of code : 
`mColorResourceId` it's hold `R.color.category_numbers` -> `mColorResourceId = R.color.category_numbers`

when i pass `mColorResourceId` directly to `setBackgroundColor(mColorResourceId);` it's doesn't change the color despite the method accept `int` value .

my question why i need this extra step `int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);` to change the color ??

Comment: While you happen to want to set the color from a resource, other developers might want to hard-code a color in Java, or load the color from a file/database, or get a color as part of a Web service response, or randomly choose a color. Hence, `setBackgroundColor()` takes the *color*, not just a resource ID of a color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setBackgroundColor()` method accepts an `int` that is supposed to be a color value in `aarrggbb` format. The resource ID `R.color.category_numbers` is also an `int`, but it is not a color value; instead it is the identifier of a `color` resource. Calling `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId)` retrieves the actual color value corresponding to `mColorResourceId`.

Part of the reason Android does this kind of indirection is to provide flexibility. The actual color returned may depend on the current theme or the device configuration and may actually change at run time (depending on how you declare your color resource).

Comment: why i pass getContext() with mColorResourceId ?? why i needed ?

Comment: @AndroidAL-Khatib - That's to allow the color retrieved to be sensitive to the current theme. For instance, suppose you define your color resource as `<color name="category_numbers">?attr/some_theme_color_name</color>`, where you've defined your own theme property `some_theme_color_name`. Then, with Android Marshmallow and later, `ContextCompat.getColor()` will use the theme set of the passed context to look up the color.